# Can anyone identify this photograph - what aircraft, when and where?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]This is a large photograph, with nothing on the reverse, so any help would be welcome.

Comment: Many thanks for your time in helping to identifyt this aircraft - much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

The twin-mast configuration is typical of the [Deperdussin Monoplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deperdussin_1910_monoplane), possibly known as the Deperdussin 1910 Monoplane, or the Deperdussin Type B monoplane, which first flew in 1910.

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deperdussin_1910_monoplane#/media/File:Deperdussin_1910_at_Shuttleworth_uncovered_2013.JPG)</sup>

This example in the [Musee de l'Air](https://www.museeairespace.fr/) in Paris has a different fuel tank and cowling configuration.

[image]
<sup>Source: [Flugzeuginfo.nat](http://www.flugzeuginfo.net/galleryphoto_en.php?photoid=10804)</sup>

The exact nomenclature is not clear from what I found. Many sources referred to this as the Type B monoplane, but it seems that although Deperdussin produced a catalogue that included Type A to Type E, they didn't commonly use those names at the time.

The aircraft is recorded as competing in a number of events around Europe and the US, so I can't place the location of the photo, nor date it more than 1910 or later.

There remains one airworthy example at the [Shuttleworth Collection](https://www.shuttleworth.org/) in the UK which I remember seeing being flown sometime in the late seventies. It takes a more intrepid pilot than I to climb aboard those early aircraft!

Comment: "more intrepid" -- surely, not least because control layouts weren't standardized until at least the onset of the Great War.  Some of the early airplanes had Zeppelin style controls (one wheel for right-left, another for up-down).  Rudder pedals weren't universal, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is a type of [Deperdussin monoplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deperdussin_1910_monoplane) which was first flown in October 1910.

Many were built, and several have survived, including an airworthy example in the [Shuttleworth Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttleworth_Collection) in England.

Most were flown in Europe, but two were used at the Central Flying School at Point Cook, near Melbourne Australia.

[image]